# Menu traversing on next and prev button click up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, html5

Can anyone optimize this code?  I am new to jQuery.

I want add class on next and previous button click.  I wrote this code that works for me, but could anyone optimize it using jQuery predefined methods?  That would be helpful.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var length = $('#slides li').size() - 1;
    var curren = 0;
    console.log(length);
    $('.next').on('click', function () {
        if (curren >= 0 && curren < length) {
            curren++;
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $('#slides li:eq(' + curren + ')').addClass('selected');
        }
    });
    $('.prev').on('click', function () {
        if (curren >= 1) {
            curren--;
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $('#slides li:eq(' + curren + ')').addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```

My HTML code:

```
<ul id="slides">
    <li class="selected">first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>six</li>
</ul>
```

CSS code:

```
.selected{
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much in the way of predefined jQuery methods to add. Here's what I came up with though...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $slides = $('#slides li'); //Save repeated selector result. 
    var length = $slides.length - 1; //size is deprecated
    var curren = 0;
    console.log(length);
    // used .click due to personal preference .on('click', does the same thing
    $('.next').click(function () {
        if (curren < length) { //Removed check that will always be true
            curren++;
            changeSelected(curren); //Moved repeated code to function
        }
    });
    $('.prev').click(function () {
        if (curren >= 1) {
            curren--;
            changeSelected(curren);
        }
    });

    function changeSelected(index) {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $slides.eq(index).addClass('selected'); //Use previously selected object
    }
});
```

Here's a link to the [doc for .size()](http://api.jquery.com/size/) where you can find it is deprecated.

Comment: FYI, I didn't know about .next() and .prev(), [Flambino's answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/33961/14909) better suits your requirements and is niftier.

Answer (score 1):

See [this very similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/33590/14370) and its answers (it's slightly different in that it loops if you keep clicking next or previous, but otherwise it's the same idea).

Here's my take on a (non-looping) version

```
$(function () { // same as (document).ready(function () {..})
  var slides = $("#slides li"); // find the slides once

  // common next/prev function
  function changeSlide(direction) {
    var target,
        current = slides.filter(".selected"); // find the current slide
    target = current[direction]();            // call either .next() or .prev()
    if(target.length) {                       // if there is a next/prev slide switch to it
      current.removeClass();
      target.addClass("selected");
    }
  }

  // add the handlers
  $(".next").on("click", function () { changeSlide('next') });
  $(".prev").on("click", function () { changeSlide('prev') });
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JfY9X/)

Comment: Very nice. Unfortunately, the buttons don't do anything in my browser, IE 9.0. I wonder why...

Comment: @DanielCook Ugh... I'd love to say I'm surprised, but _nothing_ about IE can really surprise me anymore. I have no idea what might cause it (and I don't have a Windows machine handy to check). But it works fine in Chrome/FF/Safari/Opera and on my phone...

Comment: Naturally, I'm tempted to ask on SO. It certainly looks like it should work. +1

Comment: Thought you'd like to know that this DOES work on IE 9.0. It just that your demo doesn't work on IE 9.0. I copied this independently outside of jsfiddle and it worked just fine.

Comment: @DanielCook Well that's a relief. Still pretty weird, though. Thanks for testing it!